# Generate user customized .exe from another .exe in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, exe, customization

In this project there is going to be two .exe files:

- Main, in this user can adjust settings and generate a .exe (child)
- Child, this .exe will have these user customized settings

So basically the goal is let user generate their own customized .exe. All this happen from the main .exe

I have embed a .exe (child) into another .exe (Main), as resource. Now I want make these settings applied to .exe (child)

Thx in advance

Comment: @Heandel I want to know how to apply these settings to the .exe (child)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the settings as a resource in the embedded exe, then use `BeginUpdateResource` and friends to modify it after extracting. See [Resource Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468902%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: @Erik, thanks, I have tried this mehtod, but how would I access these settings from the embeded exe

Comment: @WePro: Use `FindResource` and `LoadResource` to read it in. You could e.g. add a `RCDATA` resource containing XML, or some other format of your choosing, then just access it from the generated exe and read settings.

Comment: @Erik Oh, never thought about that, but since string table don't have name, what will be second parameter in `FindResource` ?

Comment: See what MSDN says about the 2nd parameter, it can be an ID aswell. You will have to use the MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID) macro.

Comment: @WePro: Whatever you use when you call `UpdateResource` from the parent. The parent should *1)* extract the child, *2)* Use `BeginUpdateResource`/`UpdateResource` to insert a config resource and *3)* Call `EndUpdateResource`. The child should simply extract the inserted resource and parse it to retrieve settings.

Comment: @Erik Alright, thanks, I am starting to understand, but after using `LoadResource` (successes) , how would i parse the string?
I have tried to use `LoadString` but it return `ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: @WePro: You're already able to extract the child exe resource and create the exe file - what is different with extracting a chunk of data in the child?

Comment: @Erik Idk, but could you tell steps on how to retrive the string? like what functions I should use...

Comment: @WePro: The same as you use to extract the EXE embedded in the parent.

Comment: @Erik that's exactly what I do, but `LoadString` return `ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: @WePro: You shouldn't use `LoadString` - Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194809.aspx

Comment: @Erik thx, but I am using RT_STRING to store the string, not RT_RCDATA

Comment: @WePro: You should use RT_RCDATA for arbitrary data - an EXE isn't a string.

Comment: @Erik well for EXE i use RT_RCDATA, but that's not the problem, It's the string (settings) with I store as RT_STRING

Comment: @WePro: Store them as RT_RCDATA - String tables are designed to provide locale-dependent strings to an app, RCDATA is for arbitrary data such as e.g. your config settings.

Comment: @Erik it's not possible, it gives me error, file not found,
storing as IDR_CUSTOM1        RCDATA         "SUCCESS"

Comment: @WePro: Make a config *file* and refer to that in the RCDATA entry.

Comment: @WePro: You create an EXE file, you embed it into the parent, you extract it again and store it as a file. There's not much difference if you need to create a TEXT file, embed it, extract it again and *use it directly* instead of *storing it as a file*. Sorry, I don't understand what it is you're stuck on?